# Sotring massive data by a parameter in Google Sheets

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a massive table with data that looks like. Let's call it "Initial data"

```
place | phone number | prize ($)| promotion | client status | personal manager
```

Every column has own data in it. And there can be doubles.

What's the goal
To make new sheet list (call it 'Sorted data'), where we have columns

```
sort Parameter | phone number | number of prize places | client status | personal manager | Average prize | average place
```

We have such sort parameters:

- by number of prize places in all the promotions
- by status
- by personal manager
- by average place
- by average prize

So when we choose sort parameter we have sorted data in other columns by this parameter

Any ideas on how to it can be made?

Answer (score 1):

if **Sheet1** looks like this:

[image]

then **Sheet2**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({Sheet1!A1:F1; SORT(Sheet1!A2:F, MATCH(B1, 
 {"place","phone number","price","promotion","client status","personal manager"}, 0), 
 IF(B2="ascending", 1, 0))})
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gaNx5bub43G54IaVCvZsEhUD48eF5AxguI7cM6lEgXo/copy)

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot!